# Seller pays the fees?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

Is it always the case the seller pays the fees? Is this built in the protocol or is it possible to have buyer pay the fees?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what protocol are you talking about specifically?

Answer (score 1):

What I saw in the English Auction sample is that who executes the action pays that action's fees.

The Start action is paid by who starts the action.

The Bid fees are paid by each bidder respectively

Answer (score 0):

When you create a transaction to transfer ADA from an address to another address, you also pay the transaction fees.
If you mean other type of "seller" and "buyer", please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

> When you create a transaction to transfer ADA from an address to another address, you also pay the transaction fees. If you mean other type of "seller" and "buyer", please give more details.

Alice sends ADA to Bob for 1 of Bob's NFT token. Alice is buyer and Bob is seller. But now I can see that Bob can't sell anything anyway without the transaction to sell being in the network and to be in the network he has to pay the fees. At any rate if the buyer does agree to pay the fees, they can just both agree on a rebate on the sell price.